# How to validate a Text in Asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

I want to put check to validate textbox that input value must not be similar to the values already present in database. Like:

if there is value with text "Hello" in database then user must not be allowed to save value either he writes:

`Hello`

`HELLO`

`hElLo`

`HeLLO`

`Hello` etc

I followed this http://www.dotnetperls.com/string-isupper-islower but as i am new to c# so have little confuse that how to match above defined words as all are same words `Hello`

Comment: Just as an FYI, to _you_ they are the same word but to a computer, they are very different. Look up each character in the ASCII chart to see what the difference is.

Answer (score 2):

I typically just convert both values (user input and stored value) to lower case when making the comparison.

Edit: if both values are in .NET, you could use String.Compare(s1, s2, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)

Comment: I would go for this solution also. Convert the input text to lowercase or uppercase, and in the database, compare with the lowercase or uppercase of the field. Also, if your database ir SQL Server, maybe you have already a collation that do the comparision case-insensitive. It deppends of how the database is configured.

Answer (score 0):

Do you need to do this in code? I would suggest that you just make a unique constraint on the column and let the database handle that for you. Depending on the database you are using you may need to do a little additional work to handle the case sensitivity.